# Oracle form: How to disable/enable certain blocks or fields in form by switching radio buttons?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have three radio buttons in my Oracle form. Ideally, selecting one option would enable block1 and disable block2 and block3. How this could be achieved? Global variable? Which trigger 'listen' to changes of radio button?

DB is Oracle6i.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's actually Forms 6i. There is no Oracle DB 6i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the WHEN-RADIO-CHANGED trigger.

If you've got radio buttons already defined for your form, you know that a radio group is the field you define on your form, and you can define as many radio buttons for a group as desired. Each radio button is associated with a specific value when you build the form.

When one of the radio buttons in a radio group is changed/selected, the when-radio-changed trigger will fire. At that point, depending on which button was pressed, you'll have a value for the radio group. Perform your desired action for the button pressed. So, a skeletal PL/SQL structure to implement this in your trigger could be:

```
IF :radio_group = '1' THEN
  -- enable/disable as many properties as desired for the blocks
  SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('block1',property_to_enable,PROPERTY_TRUE);
  SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('block2',property_to_disable,PROPERTY_FALSE);
  SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('block3',property_to_disable,PROPERTY_FALSE);
ELSIF :radio_group = '2' THEN
  ...
ELSIF :radio_group = '3' THEN
  ...
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it ago. Is there "easy to implement" way of creating some graphical representation of disabling blocks ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "graphical representation of disabling blocks".

Comment: Sometimes you see slightly light grey-ish different colour of disabled fields.

Comment: There really isn't a "disabled" block per se. A "disabled block" would have to mean something you define, like disabling insert/update/delete in the block, disabling all fields, etc. Perhaps you could force a popup alert to let the user know a particular block has been disabled as part of your trigger.

Comment: You can disable an item, which is usually then rendered in a greyed-out fashion, and stops the user from putting the cursor in the item. You'd still have to loop through the items in each block to disable them one by one (or enumerate each one individually), however.

Comment: is there a loop for all block in a from please !? to improve answer